# Is there a python web framework/toolkit that provides client-side form validation?

Tags: python, forms, validation, web

There are a lot of tools to build html forms using python<sup>1</sup>.  Most of these provide a means to do form validation, but only on the server side (i.e., after the submit button is pressed).  Are there any ways to implement a client-side form validation in python?  Do client-side operations this complicated require JavaScript?

<sup>1</sup> for example: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebComponents

Comment: python is a server side language.... javascript would be a client side language ... you can do client side validation with javascript ... not with python/php/etc ... also client side validation is often easily defeated so I wouldnt rely on it ...

Comment: *teeeeechnically* there have been python-in-browser implementations, both as the supported scripting language to manipulate the DOM and python-VM-in-javascript.  But in practical, deployable terms, @JoranBeasley is right.

Comment: you mean the js libraries that can more or less translate python to js(effectivly letting you write python for client side web stuff)?

Comment: One more point to @JoranBeasley's observation.  The client side is the place to do user-friendly form-field validation.  Because (as mentioned) such validation can be circumvented, there is still a need for it on the server side.  That process does not have to produce an appealing result, though, because in a correctly operating application the server side tests won't fail.  So, you log it as a runtime error to be fixed (or a possible intrusion attempt) and redirect to a generic "Oops" page.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I understand that client-side validation should only be implemented for user friendliness.  I have found that  one python web framework, web.py, is at least interested in [implementing this feature](http://webpy.org/ideas#javascript-form-support)

Comment: Don't confuse the idea of a Python web framework with running Python on the client side.  That's an option, although kind of an exotic one ... any web framework worthy of that name has the ability to generate the javascript required to do the "right" things in the client side, and to establish communication / interaction between the client and server side.  In a Python web framework, this would be done by server-side processes generating javascript as part of the HTML response package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web2py framework has client-side validation options.

There is a plugin called `plugin_ValidationEngine` that implements server-side validators on the client side, and `powerformwizard` (see https://bitbucket.org/rochacbruno/powerformwizard/overview) does something similar in a wizard-steps kind of format.

There may be others -- there are numerous contributed plug-ins for web2py.

Comment: I think more details are needed for this answer to earn some +1s.